# Show category according to location of a user

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to show categories to a user according to their location. The 'City' is listed in the `User Model` and 'Category Details' are in a different model called `CategoryModel`. The `added_by` field contains the 'email' of the users.

How do I query the users model and get the list of all users in that city and filter the list with the category model and get all the categories available under that particular city?

Here is the models:

```
class UserList(AbstractUser):
    UserMiddleName = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    usertype = models.ForeignKey(UserType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Application = models.ForeignKey(AppliationList,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    ContactCell = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    City = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
        'usertype',
        'username',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
    ]
    AbstractUser._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class CategoryList(models.Model):
    CategoryName = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    AddedBy = models.ForeignKey(UserList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    AddedDate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    UpdatedBy = models.ForeignKey(UserList, related_name="Category_Updated_By", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    UpdatedDate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    IsActive = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.CategoryName
```

Here is the query I wrote that pulls the list of users from a particular city but how do I modify it to get all the categories listed by these users?

```
USE [testenr]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getCategory]
    @city varchar(30) = NULL
AS
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[accounts_userlist] WHERE [City]=@city AND [usertype_id] = 1
GO
```

Comment: What SQL table holds the categories? It sounds like you need some type of SQL join that depends on how the tables are related. Something like...

`SELECT * FROM [accounts_userlist] LEFT JOIN [categories_table] ON accounts_userlist.ID=categories_table.ID WHERE [City]=@city AND [usertype_id] = 1`

Comment: the CategoryList holds the category table

Answer (score 0):

The code below would get you all the CategoryList instances that have same city as the request's user and also with [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) would perform a join and also fetch the related users:

```
category_in_same_city = CategoryList.objects.filter(AddedBy__City=request.user.City).select_related('AddedBy')
```